# A problem about const references and temporary objects

Tags: c++, reference, constants, temporary-objects

I understood from C++ Primer that when I bind a const reference to a non const object, the reference is bound to a temporary object whos value is the non const object.

```
int a = 1;
const int &b = a;
a = 2;
std::cout<<b;
```

According to what I understood, a temporary `const int` object whos value is `a` will be created and `b` will be initialized with it, so, it is as if I wrote this code:

```
int a = 1;
const int x = a;
const int &b = x;
a = 2;
std::cout<<b;
```

The first code prints 2, while the second prints 1. Why? Why did the value of the const reference `b` change with changing `a` while it is actually bound to a temporary const object not to `a` directly?

Comment: *According to what I understood, a temporary `const int` object whos value is `a` will be created and `b` will be initialized with it, so, it is as if I wrote this code* Is incorrect. No temporary value is involved. `b` refers directly to `a`. `b` CAN refer to a temporary (and will extend the lifespan of this temporary) but that is not what is happening here.

Comment: Does replacing `std::cout<<b;` with `std::cout<<b<<"\n"; std::cout<<((a!=b)?a:b);` show what's happening?

Comment: Take a look here: https://ideone.com/G8zmC2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understood, a temporary const int object whos value is a will be
>   created and b will be initialized with it,

You are wrong. Neither temporary object is created in this code snippet

```
int a = 1;
const int &b = a;
```

Moreover it is even unspecified in the C++ Standard whether a memory allocated for the reference b.

You should consider the reference `b` as an alias for the variable a.

As the reference refers the object `a` as a constant object you may not use the reference to change the object a. Nevertheless the object a is declared as a non-constant object. So you may change its value like

```
a = 2;
```

but you may not change it using the reference like

```
b = 2;
```

You could use the reference to change the value of the object a if the reference was declared like

```
int &b = a;
```

In this case the result of these two statements

```
a = 2;
```

and

```
b = 2;
```

will be equivalent.

As for this code snippet

```
int a = 1;
const int x = a;
const int &b = x;
a = 2;
std::cout<<b;
```

then the constant `x` is assigned with a copy of the value of the variable `a`. `x` and `a` are two different objects that occupy different extents of memory.

The reference `b` is declared as a reference to the object `x`.

```
const int &b = x;
```

So changing the object `a` does not influence on the value of the constant `x`. The constant `x` may not be changed neither directly nor by using the reference `b`.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing two different things the C++ primer is saying.

First, you are using the term "const reference" to mean a reference that is itself constant. This is not what the C++ primer means by the term "const reference". As it says:

> TERMINOLOGY: CONST REFERENCE IS A REFERENCE TO CONST
>   C++ programmers tend to cavalier in their use of the term *const reference*. Striclty speaking, what is meant by "*const reference*" is "*reference to const*". ... This usage is so common that we will follow it in this book as well.

Second, you are confusing examples and rules involving different base types (`double` and `const int`) with examples involving the same base type (`int` and `const int`).

Try this to get the effect you are describing:

```
double a = 42.0;
const int &b = a;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did use the term "const reference" to mean a reference to a const. The book mentioned the different base types example after it mentioned the examples of assigning const references to literals and same base type objects, so I thought they all have the same case.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a = 1;
const int x = a;  // x is a copy of a
const int &b = x;  // b is a reference to x, not a
a = 2;
std::cout<<b;
```

In the second snippet, b is a reference to x. (Note that x is NOT a reference to a). So changing a doesn't change x, and so it doesn't change b.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello @Mason,
>
> ```
> int a = 1;
> const int &b = a;
> a = 2;
> std::cout<<b;
> ```
>
> Here, the variable `b` is bound to a constant address or a "reference"
>   which is, `a`. You can whatever you want to do to `a` but if you were
>   to do:
>
> ```
> int c = 7;
> &b = c;
> ```
>
> *i.e.*, change the reference of `b`, you will get an error. `b` will hold whatever the value of whatever `a` as. This is kind of how
>   pass/call by reference works.
>
> ```
> int a = 1;
> const int x = a;
> const int &b = x;
> a = 2;
> std::cout<<b;
> ```
>
> Here, just like @cigien said,
>
> > In the second snippet, b is a reference to x. (Note that x is NOT a
> >     reference to a). So changing a doesn't change x, and so it doesn't
> >     change b.
>
> your variable `b` has no relation to `a`. It is only
>   related/referenced to `x` just like in the first code it was to `a`.
>   Here, any change to `a` does not affect `x`. Hence, this justifies the
>   answer ;)
>
> Best.